# Trouble loading PDFs to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload local files to S3. This code works fine for images, but the PDFs are not properly formed.

**NodeJS code:**

```
const s3=new AWS.S3();
    let type=imgData.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];
    if (type == "pdf")  type="application/pdf";
    else                type="image."+type;
    imgData=new Buffer.from(imgData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
    let params= { Bucket:bucketName, Key:fileName, Body:imgData, ACL:"public-read", ContentType:type };
    s3.upload(params, (err, data)=>{
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log("Image loaded");
        });
```

**Browser upload:**

```
<input type="file" id="co-imageUpload" style="display:none">

$("#co-imageUpload").on("change",(e)=>{                                                         
    let myReader=new FileReader();          
    myReader.onloadend=(e)=>{   
        // Send to Node JS
        }                       
    myReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);  
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to filter the data more:

```
const s3=new AWS.S3();
let type=imgData.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];
if (type == "pdf")  {
    type="application/pdf";
    imgData=new Buffer.from(imgData.replace(/^data:application\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
    }
else{
    type="image."+type;
    imgData=new Buffer.from(imgData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
    }
let params= { Bucket:bucketName, Key:fileName, Body:imgData, ACL:"public-read", ContentType:type };
s3.upload(params, (err, data)=>{
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log("Image loaded");
    });
```